# Should I edit an answer, create a new answer, or create a new question (and answer it)?

Tags: discussion, questions, answered-questions, editing

I was having some trouble with the Measure Widget and Popup and the [answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53428/115) got me on the right track: [Hiding infoWindow of ArcGIS API for JavaScript while using measure tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53262/esri-javascript-api-how-to-hide-infowindow-while-using-measure-tool)

Both answers assume that the user or site is going to hide the Measure Widget when it isn't being used anymore but that's not the case on the site I'm working on.

I figured out how to make it work and thought others might find this solution helpful. However, I'm not sure how I should share this answer. Should I:

1. Edit the answer that helped me so that it also works in this situation
2. Add a new to the existing question OR
3. Create a new question about my particular problem and answer it

I don't want to change the intent of the original author of the answer and technically my solution is more complicated than is necessary for the original question. But I don't know that my situation is different enough that it warrants its own question. What would be the most appropriate thing to do here?

Answer (score 5):

Option (#) 1 is out of the table, because it would be an "attempt to reply" (custom reason for rejecting edit-suggestions from <2k users) and could also be considered a "conflict with the author's intention" (another custom reason).

This leaves #2 and #3. A nuance from the way the question is written, I'd suggest you going with number #2, but #3 is also fine. If the latter is preferred, link both questions so all solutions will be easily found. In case going with #2, introduce the new answer giving the credits to the answer which helped you finding a different solution.

Another argument for disregarding #1, is that you should be rewarded for providing a discover of your own (assuming users will consider the answer helpful).

Comment: @bsmp I'm going to mostly agree with Andre here and just vote for his answer. However I do want to point out that it is ok to edit an answer to provide just a little more info or something - basically to *improve* it. In this case you'd be adding a whole new aspect/level to the answer. I can easily see adding your own answer and prefacing it with something like 'x's answer got me started but I wanted to keep the measure widget open so I did this'. If that's the *only* distinction, I'd go the new answer route. If there's substantially more to the changes, then you could do a new q & a.

Comment: @bsmp: I'd like to add that there's often a grey area between *improving* another's post and changing it's *intent/meaning*. I tend to err on the side of "improvement is best". Others have not always agreed; it *is* a grey zone. Ultimately, the OP can always undo such edits.